# get the latest records

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, greatest-n-per-group

I am currently still on my SQL educational journey and need some help!

The query I have is as below;

```
SELECT
Audit_Non_Conformance_Records.kf_ID_Client_Reference_Number, 
Audit_Non_Conformance_Records.TimeStamp_Creation, 
Audit_Non_Conformance_Records.Clause, 
Audit_Non_Conformance_Records.NC_type, 
Audit_Non_Conformance_Records.NC_Rect_Received, 
Audit_Non_Conformance_Records.Audit_Num


FROM Audit_Non_Conformance_Records
```

I am trying to tweak this to show only the most recent results based on `Audit_Non_Conformance_Records.TimeStamp_Creation`

I have tried using MAX() but all this does is shows the latest date for all records.

basically the results of the above give me this;

[image]

But I only need the result with the date 02/10/2019 as this is the latest result. There may be multiple results however. So for example if 02/10/2019 had never happened I would need all of the idividual recirds from the 14/10/2019 ones.

Does that make any sense at all?

Comment: Check out the questions tagged with [tag:greatest-n-per-group]

Comment: Sorry - SQL Server.

Comment: You mean "I would need all of the idividual recirds from the **14/01/2019** ones", right? Not 14/10/2019.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with a subquery:

```
 SELECT
    kf_ID_Client_Reference_Number, 
    TimeStamp_Creation, 
    Clause, 
    NC_type, 
    NC_Rect_Received, 
    Audit_Num
FROM Audit_Non_Conformance_Records a
where TimeStamp_Creation = (
    select max(TimeStamp_Creation)
    from Audit_Non_Conformance_Records
)
```

This will give you all whose `TimeStamp_Creation` is equal to the greater value available in the table.

If you want all records that have the greatest day (exluding time), then you can do:

```
SELECT
    kf_ID_Client_Reference_Number, 
    TimeStamp_Creation, 
    Clause, 
    NC_type, 
    NC_Rect_Received, 
    Audit_Num
FROM Audit_Non_Conformance_Records a
where cast(TimeStamp_Creation as date) = (
    select cast(max(TimeStamp_Creation) as date)
    from Audit_Non_Conformance_Records
)
```

---

**Edit**

If you want the latest record per `refNumber`, then you can correlate the subquery, like so:

```
SELECT
    kf_ID_Client_Reference_Number, 
    TimeStamp_Creation, 
    Clause, 
    NC_type, 
    NC_Rect_Received, 
    Audit_Num
FROM Audit_Non_Conformance_Records a
where TimeStamp_Creation = (
    select max(TimeStamp_Creation)
    from Audit_Non_Conformance_Records a1
    where a1.refNumber = a.refNumber
)
```

For performance, you want an index on `(refNumber, TimeStamp_Creation)`.

Comment: Thanks the first option is close to what I am looking for however rather than finding the very last available date, I need to find the last instance of a date in relation the the ref Number. the query above only returns one result and I assume this is like due to the fact that the table is fluid so could be updated on a regular basis?

Comment: @AaronMoran: OK, I edited my answer with a query for that.

Comment: Running it now... I'll let you know how it goes! Thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest date in SQL Server, you can express this as:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES ancr.kf_ID_Client_Reference_Number, 
       ancr.TimeStamp_Creation, 
       ancr.Clause, 
       ancr.NC_type, 
       ancr.NC_Rect_Received, 
       ancr.Audit_Num
FROM Audit_Non_Conformance_Records ancr
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, ancr.TimeStamp_Creation) DESC;
```

SQL Server is pretty good about handling dates with conversions, so I would not be surprised if this used an index on `TimeStamp_Creation`.